# Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist

Tags: mongodb, terminal, permissions, homebrew, user-permissions

Getting the above error when I try to install Mongo with homebrew from terminal. I've seen a lot of people with this same issue but none of the past recs have worked for me. I'm on an M1 Macbook Pro. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I run into the similar problem on M1 Mac PRO. I guess that your MongoDB is up and running. so if you run
$brew services start MySQL/MongoDB
System fails to grab the service (since it starts already) and returns the the error.

My solution is to uninstall MySQL. install it again. And restart the machine.

Once restarting the machine, check whether MySQL is running by
$mysqld
The system shown that SQL is up and running. then do
$mysql -uroot